# Creating Trigger function is psql "syntax error at or near "CREATE""

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, psql

Here is my postgreSQL code

```
CREATE FUNCTION connectedExhibitionFunction()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT("exName") FROM Exhibitions WHERE NEW."exName" = "exName") > 0 THEN
                IF (SELECT Count(doorLoc1) FROM Doors, ExhibitionLocations WHERE (dorLoc1=NEW.elLocation AND dorLoc2=elLocations) OR (dorLoc2=NEW.elLocation AND dorLoc1=elLocations) > 0 THEN
                        RAISE EXCEPTION 'You can't have the exhibition there, the same exhibition is in an unconnected room';
                END IF;
        END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER connectedExhibitionTrigger
        BEFORE INSERT
        ON ExhibitionsLocations
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE connectedExhibitionFunction();
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
psql:file.txt:62: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 8: CREATE FUNCTION connectedExhibitionFunction()
        ^
psql:file.txt:67: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I can't seem to figure out the error, can anybody spot anything here?

Comment: The error says `LINE 8`. I'm guessing that the statement before it is missing a semicolon.

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what the trigger is supposed to do, but it seems to me you are trying to create an unique constraint through that. Why no simply create a unique index for that? And should really learn to use the explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you missed Select  ")"  and raise exception clause couldnt be "can't"
And you can use just END  instead of END IF. As far as I know your problem is these.

Try this please.

```
 IF (SELECT Count(doorLoc1) FROM Doors, ExhibitionLocations 
  WHERE (dorLoc1=NEW.elLocation AND dorLoc2=elLocations) OR 
  (dorLoc2=NEW.elLocation AND dorLoc1=elLocations)) > 0 THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'You cant have the exhibition there, the same exhibition is in an unconnected room';
 END
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `count()` function to test for the presence of data, use the [PERFORM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) command instead. You should also `RETURN NEW` or `RETURN NULL` from the trigger function or your insert will fail by definition. With some other improvements you will end up with this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION connectedExhibitionFunction() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM * FROM Exhibitions WHERE "exName" = NEW."exName";
    IF FOUND THEN
        PERFORM * FROM Doors, ExhibitionLocations
        WHERE (dorLoc1 = NEW.elLocation AND dorLoc2 = elLocations)
           OR (dorLoc2 = NEW.elLocation AND dorLoc1 = elLocations);
        IF FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'You can''t have the exhibition there, the same exhibition is in an unconnected room';
            RETURN NULL; -- Make the INSERT fail
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW; -- Make the INSERT succeed
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```